# Disable @PreAuthorize when using the function in a specific context

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-security, spring-data-rest

I'm migrating an application with custom rest controllers to `spring data rest`. One problem I'm facing is that I had to add `@PreAuthrozie` annotations directly to my repositories instead of having them at a controller level. This is fine except some special cases.

1. The whole user repository is protected by a `USER_ACCESS` privilege. When the user authenticates, a new token is generated and the user has to be saved. Problem is, at this point there is no authentication in the `Security Context` so the request returns with `403`
2. I have some code that on startup has all classes implementing `PermissionProvider` and saves new permissions to the database. Again, at this point there is no authentication in the `Security Context` so this fails since the repository is protected by `PERMISSION_ACCESS` privilege

I can manually create a tmp authentication that I set before the call then clear the context but this seems like a hack and can be problematic. Is there a way to disable `@PreAuthorize` in some context?

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can work around this is to in cases 1. and 2. call another method in the repository that is not annotated with `@PreAuthorize`. This method would then call the methods annotated with `@PreAuthorize`. Since they are in the same class, `@PreAuthorize` has no effect. The reason being the way Spring AOP and CGLIB work. A proxy class is created that extends your class, providing the logic behind the `@PreAuthorize` behavior. When you call a method within the same class, such a call does not go through the proxy class, and as a consequence `@PreAuthorize` has no effect.

Comment: Problem is that `@PreAuthorize` is on repository level not on method level. To move it to method level, I would have to override all methods in all of my repositories to add the annotation

Comment: There is no other way in my opinion.